# Diagonalizable stochastic matrix that satisfies an equation

Tags: markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

Given an arbitrary discrete probability distribution $a = (a_1, ..., a_n)$ and another arbitrary discrete probability distribution $b = (b_1, ..., b_n)$, what is the easiest known way to find a diagonalizable $n \times n$ stochastic matrix $M$ such that $M \cdot a = b$?

Comment: Surely the easiest known way is to put $b$ in every column?

Comment: I would love that to work. How do we know the matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: @TobiasFritz I would suggest you to post it as an answer, so that you can grab the bounty and this question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $M$ to be the stochastic matrix which has $b$ in every column. Then $M$ maps every probability vector to $b$, and in particular $Ma = b$.

Concerning diagonalizability, choose any basis which contains $b$ as first basis vector and such that all other basis vectors $c$ satisfy $\sum_i c_i = 0$. In such a basis, $M = \mathrm{diag}(1,0,\ldots,0)$.